# Does Chrome stop certain javascript code from running because of its extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a small code in my page with

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function doPost() {
 document.forms["form"].submit();
}  
  function Func1Delay()
{
setTimeout("doPost()", 0);
}
```

....

```
   <body onload="Func1Delay()">
```

I have this error in the console saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

and on the right, it's due to the chrome extension MeasureIt. When I disable it, my script works. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: How does it "blocks" your code?

Comment: I suppose its possible for an extension to conflict with JavaScript from the page. Does the error still occur if your code is not in the page?

Comment: Yeah, i remove the javascript code and left the body onload ="functionDelay()" there. It still has that error.

Comment: What happens if you rename that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is YES.
But the complete answer is NO, it's not Chrome, but some extension who interfere with your code.
For example:

1) A content script can add a listener and use stopPropagation.  In this case your code won't receive that event.  I can image a more specific scenario where the content script fails and therefore prevents other listeners to execute.

2) A content script can mess with your page's  elements.  It can remove some, and add its owm.  What would happen if the extension add a SCRIPT element with a var or function named exactly the same that one of yours?

We cannot be sure about how "well" the extension's code is written.

By the way, there is a lot of Chrome's extensions that interfere with pages.  Some months ago Skype extension for Chrome was found guilty of interfere and destabilize web pages and video playback in that browser.

Comment: That particular extension also broke access to one of my pages.